# WPF Different ComboBox ItemsSource for each row. Data from Database

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to create a dynamic number of comboboxes with different values for each row with WPF.
The data for the rows and comboboxes come from 2 SELECTs. 
The first SELECT gets some Information(Textboxes inside Row) and the second SELECT gets Information based on the first SELECT(Combobox).

What I want to know is: Is that possible and if yes, can someone tell me how?

Thanks for all answers in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a control like ItemsControl to hold your comboboxes. And a DataTemplate containing a combobox.

Xaml:

```
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" Style="{x:Null}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ComboBox Width="350" Margin="5" ItemsSource="{Binding}"></ComboBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Code behind:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = new List<List<string>>() {
        new List<string>() {"Item 1","Item 2","Item 3"},
        new List<string>() {"Item 4","Item 5","Item 6"},
        new List<string>() {"Item 7","Item 8","Item 9"},
        new List<string>() {"Item 10","Item 11","Item 12"}
    };
}
```